# find an item from ArrayDeque and push it to last in Java

Tags: java, deque, arraydeque

I have and `ArrayDeque<Integer>` which I am looping through to find an element and once found I want to push it to the bottom of the deque. But it gives me `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` Error.

Any help with a demo is appreciated. Maybe using a different util as well.

Answer (score 0):

using this may help you

If you are using a pojo havin the Equals implemented is sufficient to help the list to remove the wanted Object

the pojo class

```
 class User {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }



    /**
     * Get the value of password
     *
     * @return the value of password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of password
     *
     * @param password new value of password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of username
     *
     * @return the value of username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of username
     *
     * @param username new value of username
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final User other = (User) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.username, other.username)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.password, other.password)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nUser{" + "username=" + username + ", password=" + password + '}';
    }


}
```

use case tutorial

```
    ArrayDeque arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque();
    arrayDeque.add("A");
    arrayDeque.add("B");
    arrayDeque.add("C");
    arrayDeque.add("D");

    System.out.println(arrayDeque);

    arrayDeque.remove("A");
    arrayDeque.add("A");
    System.out.println(arrayDeque);

    ArrayDeque<User> usersDeque = new ArrayDeque();
    final User userTaleb = new User("Taleb", "Mohammed");
    usersDeque.add(userTaleb);
    usersDeque.add(new User("Mansouri", "Abdellah"));
    usersDeque.add(new User("Ziane", "Nadir"));

    System.out.println(usersDeque);

    usersDeque.remove(userTaleb);
    usersDeque.add(userTaleb);

    System.out.println(usersDeque);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your example, but you problem is you use two different iterators (they could be implicit by JVM, e.g. when you use `for loop`) for reading and for modification `deque`. Each `Iterator` contains counter to check concurrent modification. To avoid `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` you have to use one `Iterator` at the same time:

**Variant 1:**

```
public static void moveLast(Deque<Integer> deque, int val) {
    if (deque.remove(val))
        deque.add(val);
}
```

**Variant 2:**

```
public static void moveLast(Deque<Integer> deque, int val) {
    boolean exists = false;

    for (int i = 0, size = deque.size(); i < size; i++) {
        Integer item = deque.remove();

        if (exists)
            deque.add(item);
        else if (val == item)
            exists = true;
        else
            deque.add(item);
    }

    if (exists)
        deque.add(val);
}
```